# Django cms plugin POST request

Tags: django, plugins, content-management-system, request

I wrote simple plugin to add comments onto page using form.

Here is the plugin code:

```
class KomentarzePlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CMSPlugin
    name = _("Komentarze plugin")
    render_template = "komentarze/komentarze_wtyczka.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        request = context['request']
        print 'weszlo1'
        print request.method
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = KomentarzForm(request.POST)
                print 'weszlo2'
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                    tresc = form.cleaned_data['tresc']
                    strona = request.current_page
                    data = timezone.datetime.now()
                    k = Komentarz(autor=user, data=data, tresc=tresc, strona=strona)
                    k.save()

        context.update({
                'instance': instance,
                'placeholder': placeholder,
                'komentarze': Komentarz.objects.all().filter(strona=request.current_page).order_by('-data'),
                'forma': KomentarzForm()
        })

        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(KomentarzePlugin)
```

When I restart server, fill the form with data, hit submit, then if statement with POST method is satisfied and function enters it, post is added to database and shown. But, when I try to do it again, it don't even print request.method to console, which means it is empty. Restarting server fixes the problem. Also it doesn't work when I restart the server, do some random menu clicks, and then try to fill and send the form.

Any guess?

Comment: Did you know that Django has a built-in comments framework that you can add to any page? https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments

Comment: I know, but my task is to do my own.

Comment: I see. Well, you won't be able to do the post handling in the render method of the plugin due to the way Django CMS caches plugins. You'll need to move the post handling to a view.

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved my problem. In KomentarzePlugin class I added:

```
cache = False
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost went crazy because of that :D